# Jquery serialzed form datas are displayed as string on server side while sending using ajax

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, forms

I wanted to send 3 objects to my server. 2 payment response objects and one object contains my form input field values. But if i send it together like i shown below, the formData is treated as string in server side which i cant access. If i only send the formData there are no issues. There is no issue if i only send other 2 objects. How can i get it as an json object on server side?

```js
const formData = $('#checkoutForm').serialize();
```

this function is called after the response from razorpay. Payment and order are the responses from razorpay

```js
function verifyPayment(payment, order) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/verify-payment',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      payment,
      order,
      formData,
    },
    success: function (response) {
      console.log('payment status', response);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    },
  });
}
```

console for req.body in server:

```js
form data from verify patment=== {
  payment: {
    razorpay_payment_id: 'pay_NQKts6UWsReLkf',
    razorpay_order_id: 'order_NQKtkMV1mv3AiT',
    razorpay_signature:
      'beb2eac3df927dd1901da8f79140be832bb6f662135ed04a3f23ded32ab80e9f',
  },
  order: {
    id: 'order_NQKtkMV1mv3AiT',
    entity: 'order',
    amount: '129900',
    amount_paid: '0',
    amount_due: '129900',
    currency: 'INR',
    receipt: '8774a2511705637831834',
    offer_id: '',
    status: 'created',
    attempts: '0',
    created_at: '1705637832',
  },
  formData:
    'fullName=&phoneNUmber=&email=&house=&landMark=&city=&district=&state=&pincode=&selectedAddress=Ahammed+Zulaikh%0D%0AManthadathil(H)%0D%0AChalilpara%0D%0AMALAPPURAM%0D%0A676508%0D%0AMalappuram%0D%0AKERALA%0D%0A919605633278&deliveryInstruction=&totalPrice=1299&paymentMethod=Online+Payment&productId=6 593d05163f67fb7dd7b3182&productPrice=1299&orderProductQty=1',
};
```

`console.log(typeOf req.body.formData)` gives a string.

Comment: Looks like JSON would make more sense here. Would the be a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `.serialize()` returns an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` **string**.

Given the object structures of your existing `payment` and `order` properties, I would recommend sending the request payload as JSON.

You certainly don't need jQuery for any of this.

First, capture the form data as a plain object

```js
const formData = Object.fromEntries(
  new FormData(document.getElementById("checkoutForm")),
);
```

Then send a request to your API

```js
async function verifyPayment(payment, order) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("/verify-payment", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({ payment, order, formData }),
    });

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`${res.statusText} ${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`);
    }

    console.log("payment status", await res.text()); // or res.json()
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

On the server-side, you'd just need to ensure you were able to handle JSON request bodies using the appropriate middleware

```js
app.use(express.json());
```

---

If you really still wanted to use jQuery to send the request, it would look like this

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/verify-payment',
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  data: JSON.stringify({ payment, order, formData }),
  success: function(response) {
    console.log('payment status', response);
  },
  error: function(_, ...err) {
    console.error(...err);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . I was stuck at it for almost a day. This really solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

you can use this

const formData = JSON.stringify($('#checkoutForm').serializeArray());

function verifyPayment(payment, order) {
$.ajax({
url: '/verify-payment',
type: 'POST',
contentType: 'application/json',  // Set content type to JSON
data: JSON.stringify({
payment,
order,
formData
}),
success: function(response) {
console.log('payment status', response);
},
error: function(error) {
console.log(error);
}
});
}

Comment: It will not work. I already got it from chatGPT.

Comment: Why double-encode `formData`? That just means more work on the server-side to decode it

Comment: Hello phil, iam so greatfull to get a replay from you. Iam beginner trying to learn full stack development. I dont know very much. Can you please tell me where did i encoded my data?

Comment: @AhammedZulaikh sorry, my comment was a question to the author of this answer, not you